# Hadoop, running tasks

Tags: java, hadoop

How do I programmatically add tasks to hadoop and run in my Java application?
Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: You can submit Jobs to Hadoop and let them run through your Java application on your cluster. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes that's what I want to do. But how ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In java this is quite easy:

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
Job job = new Job(conf);
job.setJarByClass(YOUR_MAPPER.class);
job.setMapperClass(YOUR_MAPPER.class);
job.setReducerClass(YOUR_REDUCER.class);
job.setOutputKeyClass(YOUR_OUTPUT_KEY.class);
job.setOutputValueClass(YOUR_OUTPUT_VALUE.class);
FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path("YOUR_INPUT_PATH"));
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("YOUR_OUTPUT_PATH"));
System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
```

If you need to submit it to a cluster you have to add these values to the configuration object:

```
conf.set("fs.default.name", "hdfs://localhost:9000");
conf.set("mapred.job.tracker", "localhost:9001");
```

You should replace the ports and hostname to the configured values in the cluster conf's directory.

Comment: But, in order to run job on execution on hadoop, I have to enter "bin/hadoop jar hadoop.jar main.UrlFetch input output" every time.
I want to run job (for example, parsing many web sites) from my web application, sometimes control for completion and pass the results to my web app.

Comment: actually, this snippet can be used in any application.